# How to get current activity in Android app development in API 25? (note: previous code might have been deprecated)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I noticed `getActivity()`, doesn't work anymore in API 25.

Anyone know how to get the current activity?

Comment: There is no concept in Android of "current activity". After all, with Android 7.0 multi-window environments, an app can have zero, one, or several activities that are visible. I recommend that you edit your question and explain **in detail** what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you already answered my question. thanks! I was trying to ask this because when you have to pass an argument for the current activity you are in (MainActivity.class) you could instead use getActivity();